# Unexplained crashing of Autostart app

Tags: android, android-intent, boot, autostart, android-broadcast

MainActivity code is:

```
    package com.example.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class Boot extends BroadcastReceiver{

        /*@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                context.startActivity(i);  
        }*/
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // make sure you receive "BOOT_COMPLETED"
            if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
            {
                // Start the service or activity 
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                context.startActivity(i); 
            }
        }

   }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.second"
            android:label="second" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".Boot" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the Emulator the app starts ,(emulator for 4.0.3 ICS) but on my ICS 4.0.4 SonyEricsson it crashs also tested this with a Samsung Galaxy 2.2 Froyo Android still the same problem kindly help.

I added Thread sleep as the app was crashing at phone startup so thought that is happening due to over load of resources on the device this was deemed useless!

I think this the excerpt from LOGCAT that is defining the problem

```
I/ActivityManager(  274): Start proc com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail for broadcast com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail/com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.update.SoftwareUpdateSystemBroadcastReceiver: pid=805 uid=10014 gids={3003, 1007, 1015}
D/PhoneStatusBar(  359): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK HOME recent* CLOCK >
D/PhoneStatusBar(  359): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back* home* recent clock* >
I/ActivityManager(  274): Start proc com.example.testing for broadcast com.example.testing/.Boot: pid=824 uid=10153 gids={}
E/AndroidRuntime(  824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.testing.Boot: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testing.Boot
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2111)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testing.Boot
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2106)
E/AndroidRuntime(  824):    ... 10 more
I/BootReceiver(  274): Copying /proc/last_kmsg to DropBox (SYSTEM_LAST_KMSG)
```

Comment: Please inculde stacktrace of your crash.

Comment: Will Android provide a Logcat while its switching on ? and connected t o the development PC?

Comment: *'it crashes'*... What are we supposed to do with your problem?! You really need to provide a stack trace or at least tell us what part is crashing!

Comment: Android always provides strack trace information. You can even grab it after the application crashed without being connected to your development PC using `adb logcat`

Comment: In tis case you could try to use custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and save you stacktrace to a file. But before this you probably should try to move your receiver code to a different file. You should never use it as non-static inner class of `Activity`.

Comment: @Veger it crashes when the phone boots and if the boot is completed the app should have started but instead its force closes

Comment: Grab the log information using `adb logcat` and check if for indications what went wrong... (or if you cannot find it: update your answer with this information)

Comment: Updated the Answer with LOGCAT

Comment: I think its not able to find the Boot which has to be ignited by the bootreceiver if this is true! then why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logcat kind of explains your problem... `com.example.testing.Boot` does not exists... Which is true as `Boot` is an inner class of `MainActivity`, so it should at least have been `com.example.testing.MainActivity.Boot`.

But, I do not think it is allowed to have an inner class as receiver, as it is unknown to the system which 'outer class' should be invoked? So put it in its own file in the `com.example.testing` package.

Comment: Ok this seems to be the very likely solution to my problem.

Comment: I do not know how much experience you have with broadcast receivers, but check the [article by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for some additional details on them

Comment: Don't know... Did your code actually got called on the emulator? Check your emulator logcat for more info..? There are quite a few differences between a real device and the emulator. So when something works on the emulator it does not say (very) much about whether it works on a real device...

Comment: Yes True that's why I believe testing on my Real Device